# ASP.NET создание почтового ящика

Tags: asp.net, c#, email

Всем добрый день. Интересует следующий вопрос:
Допустим, есть сайт, на котором посетитель должен зарегистрироваться.
При регистрации, посетителю регистрируется почтовый ящик типа user_name@myhost.com
можно ли зарегистрировать почтовый ящик пользователю программно, а не через панель управления хостингом вручную? Возможно, хостер должен предоставлять эту возможность отдельно? А то я до этого никогда этим вопросом не интересовался, и не в курсе, что да как. :)

Comment: Вы сами ответили на Ваш вопрос! Для регистрации нового почтового ящика требуется доступ к серверу (демону) почтового сервиса, которым "заведует" хостер.

Comment: Да, к тому же, ещё и у хостера только что уточнил. Да, жаль. :)